# How processes share the logical address spaces?

Tags: operating-system

Cooperating processes share logical address spaces. Can anyone please tell me what actually they share and what is the mechanism which allows them sharing ???

Answer (score 0):

Processes DO NOT share logical address spaces. They share a common system area but that is all. The operating system (and sometimes hardware) assigns a range of addresses for the system space. That range of logical addresses is the same for all processes.

The remaining addresses are the user space. That range of logical addresses are unique to each process.